# Websocket connection drops using Golang's gorilla/websocket package

Tags: node.js, go, websocket

I'm attempting to port a NodeJS script that establishes and maintains a Websocket connection to a third-party server to Go using the [gorilla/websocket](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket) package. In the [Node script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7c169e995d13a943d3f494c88cac7a17), a pong is received following a ping, and the connection is kept alive indefinitely. In the [Go script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/69b8dca0172803fccb45dfeb5d310133), ping/pong works but the connection is dropped by the server after about 30 seconds.

I suspect that the pings that are sent using the Go websocket package are malformed, but I can't pinpoint the cause of this. Comparing the captured, encrypted network traffic while running these programs shows no difference in the response length of the TCP requests and responses, so this may not be the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**websocket.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// npm install websocket@1.0.25 --save
const WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
const client = new WebSocketClient();

let lastPing = new Date().getTime();

client.on('connectFailed', function(error) {
    console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
});

client.on('connect', function(connection) {
    console.log('Connected to Server...');
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
    });
    connection.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Connection Closed');
    });
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
      if (message.type === 'utf8') {
        console.log(message.utf8Data);
      }
    });
    connection.on('pong', function(){
      console.log('[pingpong] response took', (new Date().getTime() - lastPing) + 'ms');
    })

    function send(message) {
      if (connection.connected) {
          connection.sendUTF(message);
      }
    }

    // Send a ping every 10s
    // to keep the connection live
    setInterval(function(){
      lastPing = new Date().getTime();
      connection.ping();
    }, 10000);
});

client.connect('wss://ws.radarrelay.com/0x/v0/ws');
```

**websocket.go**

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var addr = "wss://api.radarrelay.com/0x/v0/ws"

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.SetFlags(0)

    timeoutDuration := 2 * time.Minute

    interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

    c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(addr, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dial:", err)
    } else {
        log.Println("Connected to server")
    }

    c.SetPongHandler(func(str string) error {
        log.Println("pong received", str)
        return nil
    })

    defer c.Close()

    done := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        defer c.Close()
        defer close(done)
        for {
            c.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(timeoutDuration))
            _, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("read:", err)
                return
            }
            if len(message) >= 2 {
                message = message[2:]
            }
            log.Printf("recv: %s", message)
        }
    }()

    ticker := time.NewTicker(10 * time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for {
        select {
        case _ = <-ticker.C:
            err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.PingMessage, []byte{})
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("write:", err)
                return
            } else {
                log.Println("ping sent")
            }
        case <-interrupt:
            log.Println("interrupt")
            // To cleanly close a connection, a client should send a close
            // frame and wait for the server to close the connection.
            err := c.WriteMessage(
                websocket.CloseMessage,
                websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, ""))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("write close:", err)
                return
            }
            select {
            case <-done:
            case <-time.After(time.Second):
            }
            c.Close()
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's see some code.

Comment: @Peter See the linked gists.

Comment: @MaxGillett: Always include the code for a [mcve] in your post (see [ask]).

Comment: Paste that code here. Site rules dictate that code must be included in the question, not just linked to.

Comment: Because you report that the client receives pongs, it seems that the pings must be well-formed.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Yes, but malformed from the perspective of this particular third-party server. The above Golang script holds a connection for any other websocket server I can throw at it, including servers I spin up on my own. I would like to compare the unencrypted content of the ping frames sent by each script, but I don't know how to go about doing this.

Comment: To log the unencrypted data, add `fmt.Println("frame: %x %x\n", buf0, buf1)` [to the Go code](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/eb925808374e5ca90c83401a40d711dc08c0c0f6/conn.go#L376) and `console.log(output);` [to the JS code](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/d941f975e8ef6b55eafc0ef45996f4198013832c/lib/WebSocketFrame.js#L270).

Comment: Based on a quick inspection of the code, it looks like both packages send the same data for a ping: 0x89, 0x80 and a four byte mask.

Comment: addr is different between the two- wss://ws.radarrelay.com/0x/v0/ws for node and wss://api.radarrelay.com/0x/v0/ws for the go version. Those resolve to different IPs, do they have different ingress infrastructure?

Comment: @JonahBenton Well, that's embarrassing -- this is the problem. Good catch. If you create an answer below I can accept it.

Comment: @max-gillett Cool! Happy to help. Always good to have a second pair of eyes look something over. Happens to me all the time that someone catches a little nit. To a first approximation, SO is just that service at scale. :) Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The addr is different between the two. The node code is talking to

```
wss://ws.radarrelay.com/0x/v0/ws
```

And the go code is talking to:

```
wss://api.radarrelay.com/0x/v0/ws
```

Looks like those resolve to different IPs, so perhaps they have different ingress infrastructure, and there is a timeout on the api subdomain that doesn't exist on the ws subdomain.

Comment: If this turns out to be the real problem, then nice catch :-)